# What is The Kremlin?

Tags: russian-federation, terminology

This is probably a pretty stupid question, but I just don't know the answer. I hear people on news radio shows, on TV, and I've seen articles that talk about "The Kremlin" but nobody ever describes what they are. The way they're talked about, it sounds like The Kremlin is a group of people (a political group? a cultural group? ethnic group?). I've tried searching around a little, but what I've found is information about buildings, and what is essentially an old fortress. This just makes it even more confusing for me.

Can someone explain to me what The Kremlin is?

Answer (score 19):

The Kremlin is a building complex in Russia that is the official residence of the Russian president, and by extension is essentially the government headquarters. In at least Western media, "Kremlin" is used to mean "the Soviet/Russian government," like "the White House" or "Washington" is used to refer to the US government.

Comment: Kremlin isn't just official residence of Russian president - it's any government fortress. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kremlin

Comment: @user4012 "kremlin" (with small "k") isn't a government fortress - it's a central fortress inside town or ancient town itself. Instead, "Kremlin" (with capital "K") is the official residence of the Russian president.

Comment: @PavelMayorov - I'm unaware of any kremlins that were not government's historically. But I think strictly speaking you're correct semantically

Answer (score 5):

Generally, "[kremlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kremlin_(fortification))" (with the lowercase k) is the Russian word for *citadel* or *fortress*. Like elsewhere, early on, its walls encompass the whole settlement; then only its central/historical part; then, frequently (but not necessarily), it only remains the residence of the ruler/government.

"[The Kremlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kremlin)" is the Moscow Kremlin, the most famous one. It is the main official residence of the Russian President (or another [head of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Secretary_of_the_Communist_Party_of_the_Soviet_Union)). Notably, this is not the residence of the [[head of] the government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Minister_of_Russia), who, historically, plays a very technical role.

The figure of speech when a term for the whole is used in place of its part (or vice versa) is called [synecdoche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche). It is very common, particularly in political speech. In this sense, "The Kremlin", "Moscow" or even "Russia" is the same thing, just like "The White House", "Washington" and "the US".